# How do I use the node.js request module to make an SSL call with my own certificate?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, request, certificate

I'm using node.js and this request module to make HTTP calls to another server.

https://github.com/mikeal/request

It works great.  I now need to modify this code to make the calls over SSL, using my company's SSL certificate.  In the request module's docs, it says this about the strictSSL option:

"strictSSL - Set to true to require that SSL certificates be valid. Note: to use your own certificate authority, you need to specify an agent that was created with that ca as an option."

This sounds like what I need to do, but I don't understand this phrase: "specify an agent that was created with that ca as an option.".

1) What do they mean by "an agent"?
2) How do I "specify an agent"
3) How do I create the agent "with that ca as an option"?

A code example would be amazing, but any leads would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you get what you needed. I need to do the same thing. Can you share some example of how you did it ?, thanks

Answer (score 14):

This largely elaborates on [Peter Lyons' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15255239/1080564), providing an example.

I am assuming that you are requesting a domain running over HTTPS with a certificate signed by *your own* certificate authority (ca).

When using the [request library](https://github.com/mikeal/request), as you do, there is no need to actually instantiate the agent yourself, you can simply provide some `agentOptions` to the request you are making. The following is an example:

```
request({
  method: "POST",
  uri: "https://localhost/entries",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: "someEntry"
  }),
  agentOptions: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync("certs/ca.cert.pem")
  }
}, function(error, httpResponse, body) {
  //handle response
});
```

The important thing here is the `agentOptions`, which you provide the certificate of a ca. All domains using certificates signed by the ca are now accepted. Imagine a ca **CA1** has signed three domains, **D1**, **D2**, **D3**. Setting the ca to **CA1** results in allowing requests to all of the domains **D1**, **D2**, **D3** (but not **D4** signed by a different ca).

Point being: the `"certs/ca.cert.pem"` must be the certificate of the signing certificate authority.

Comment: What if I want to accept a certificate that was signed by an intermediary? I have tried all combinations (CA, IA; CA; even IA, CA) but my cert is never verified (`UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`, or `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT`)

Comment: how can I do this using fetch?

Comment: @Sibelius what do you mean?

Comment: using node-fetch

Answer (score 5):

1. "an agent" means an instance of [http.Agent](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_class_http_agent) from the node standard `http` module
2. The docs indicate this agent instance would be passed to `request` in the `pool` option I believe, although I haven't done it myself and the docs are indeed sparse on details here. Based on skimming the code, I think you might just need `options.ca`
3. request seems to directly support `options.ca`  and [uses it here](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/index.js#L480) in `getAgent`

So my guess is maybe just pass in `options.ca` as a string that is the public key of your company's certificate authority and see if request does the right thing from there.

Answer (score 2):

```
const request = require('request');

request.post({
                url: strRSAUrl,
                agentOptions: {
                    ca: fs.readFileSync('path-to-cacert.pem')
                },
                form: {
                    some_key: some_value,
                }
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                objResponse.send(body);
            });
```

For more details,you can refer from [`nodejs#request`](https://github.com/request/request)

Answer (score 1):

perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem, but in my experience you don't need to do anything special at all if you `require('https')`, the call automatically goes out over SSL.

I just tested this with my google maps api call and indeed if I `require('http')` Google complains that it wants the call to come in over SSL, but when I add the `s` everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `agentOptions` property to attach the certificates and also we can add `rejectUnauthorized: true` to ensure invalid request to be rejected.

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");

request(
    {
        url: requestURL.url,
        method: requestURL.method,
        headers: custom_headers
            ? custom_headers
            : {
                  "Content-Type": "text/plain ; charset=utf-8"
              },
        body: requestParam,
        agentOptions: {
            ca: [
                fs.readFileSync("./ROOT.pem"),
                fs.readFileSync("./Intermediate.pem"),
            ],
        },
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(error, "error");
        console.log(response, response);
        console.log(body, "body");
    }
);
```