# can run serve -s build with https in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need to run "serve -s build" with https in reactjs application.

Try to run HTTPS with Npm and it is worked fine but when run production build using"serve -s build" the production run with HTTP not HTTPS.

serve -s build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [serve-https](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-https) instead.

And if you are testing it in `localhost` in the Google Chrome you can enalble `Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.` in `chrome://flags/`

**UPDATE**

> serve-https seems unmaintened and its homepage
> git.daplie.com/Daplie/serve-https is not accessible at the time this
> post is written. *– psychoslave*

- [Please refer to the answer by *psychoslave*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75029732/7480771)
- [npm http-server with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35127383/7480771)

Comment: serve-https seems unmaintened and its homepage https://git.daplie.com/Daplie/serve-https is not accessible at the time this post is written.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass ssl information and the switch operate automatically.

```bash
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
# Fill all prompted demands, "127.0.0.1" as "Common name" is OK for development environment
serve -s build --ssl-cert cert.pem --ssl-key key.pem
```

## See also

- [npm http-server with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127383/npm-http-server-with-ssl)