# Request, Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to make simple POST HTTP request by using `request` module:

```
var request = require("request");
var form = {form: {some: "form", attributes: "attrs"}}
request.post("https://example.com", form)
   .on('response', function(response) {

   if (response.statusCode === 200) {
     console.log("DONE");
   } else {
     console.log("FAIL");
   }
});
```

When I launch this code it throws me this error message:

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
at Error (native)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1057:38)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:596:8)
```

I think this is happening because url has `https`, but I don't know how to fix this error.

How to disable checking certificate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `"rejectUnauthorized": false` as option:

```
request.post({url: "https://example.com", "rejectUnauthorized": false}, form)
   .on('response', function(response) {

   if (response.statusCode === 200) {
     console.log("DONE");
   } else {
     console.log("FAIL");
   }
});
```

Or add the appropiate certificate via https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas

```
require('ssl-root-cas').inject();
```

Comment: When I use your code, it throws me `Error: Invalid URI "/"` error message.

Comment: Try `request.post({uri: "https://example.com", rejectUnauthorized: false}` but it should be the same

Comment: I changed as you asked, It still throws `Error: Invalid URI "/"` error.

Comment: Disabling the cert verification is potentially dangerous and definitely NOT a good solution, a workaround at best but a massive security flaw in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with disabling ssl certificate verification under File->Settings
[Settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNOJ3.png)

Comment: with node ? a File menu ?