# Error Using CA Cert for ldaps using Passport in Express and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ldap, passport.js

I'm using passport with Express in NodeJS to use LDAP authentication for my application and I am getting an error:

```
events.js:154
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1065:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:593:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.ssl.onnewsession.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:425:38)
```

I have all the ldap options in a config file and then I add the ca stuff like so:

```
opts.tlsOptions.ca = [fs.readFileSync('./config/ldap.pem')];
passport.use(new LdapStrategy({server: opts}));
```

I googled the error and found the following answer on here: [Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs) so I added the following before I initialize my ldap stuff:

```
require('ssl-root-cas').addFile('./config/ldap.pem');
```

However this solution didn't work for me at all. I am at my wits end. I really hope someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was provided the wrong certificate and this was the result. I was given the correct certificate and this error has stopped and everything works.