# Node.js web-push library

Tags: node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, web-push

---

I'm trying to use the [web-push](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push) node.js library to send a push-notification to a chrome browser.

after firing the

```
webpush.sendNotification(pushSubscription,payload)
```

method i get this response -

```
{ Error: unable to verify the first certificate
at Error (native)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1060:38)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:584:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

i'm guessing it's a SSL issue? How can i test this library over localhost?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs)

Comment: Can you still reproduce this?

Comment: Yes. It happens when you create the node server with http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by creating the nodejs server with https and the correct keys.

Not sure if this is the correct implementation but it got it up and running for us.

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('server.pfx')
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
    //Do push things
}).listen(443);
```

Comment: This is pretty weird if I'm honest. I don't see how this would help. Could you provide more sample code and open an issue on the project: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push/issues/new