# Error installing mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I'm a beginner in nodejs and mongodb. I have been working on a project for a while using MEAN stack. It also uses mongojs and mongoose extentions which were working fine until now.
I'm following this [tutorial](https://github.com/michaelcheng429/meanstacktutorial).

A server.js file helps me connect my project with the database. I'm getting the following mongodb error on running the server.js file which was not present until now.

```
        C:\Program Files\nodejs\easy-node-authentication-local1>node server1
    module.js:327
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\mongojs\lib\collection.js:1:77)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

I'm unable to install mongodb using 'npm install mongodb' because of the following error.

```
        C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install mongodb
    npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/-/mongodb-2.2.12.tgz
    npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Can anyone help me understand this problem.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy or something?

Comment: No. It is a simple web application. I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/michaelcheng429/meanstacktutorial.

Comment: I have made the edits. I would really appreciate your help. @JohnnyHK

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the need of `server.js` for installing mongoDB. 
But I recently tried installing, and it worked for me

make sure you have all dependencies installed.

I suggest you to `npm install tar -g` and then `npm install mongodb -g`

Answer (score 0):

have you any proxy in network?
If yes you must configure with npm. Check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas)