# Meteor Email Server with Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: email, meteor, certificate, self-signed, pki

I am trying to have my meteor application send an e-mail using my own e-mail server.

I installed my e-mail's server certs onto my meteor app server by doing:

- `openssl s_client -connect my-email-server.com:443 <<<'' | openssl x509 -out /tmp/mycert`
- `cp /tmp/mycert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`
- `update-ca-certificates`

Which appeared to install correctly (I also used `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` to install the certs) (ref: [90607](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90607))

I then start my meteor app in the following ways, none of which work to successfully send my e-mail:

- `MAIL_URL=smtp://user:password@my-email-server.com:587 meteor`
- `CAFILE="/tmp/mycert" MAIL_URL=smtp://user:password@my-email-server.com:587 meteor`

The code I am calling in my application is:

```
Email.send({
            to: emailAddress,
            from: "user@my-email-server.com",
            subject: "Example Email",
            text: "The contents of our email in plain text.",
        });
```

The error I am getting is:

```
I20180114-04:09:25.698(-5)? Exception while invoking method 'emailMethod' Error: unable to verify the first certificate
I20180114-04:09:25.698(-5)?     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1103:38)
I20180114-04:09:25.698(-5)?     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
I20180114-04:09:25.699(-5)?     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
I20180114-04:09:25.699(-5)?     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:637:8)
I20180114-04:09:25.699(-5)?     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:467:38)
```

`Exception while invoking method 'emailMethodHere' Error: unable to verify the first certificate`

When I run the meteor app via `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 MAIL_URL=smtp://user:password@my-email-server.com:587 meteor` then it works as expected (bypassing the cert entirely), so I know the trust/certificate is the issue. Where is my error? How do I tell meteor to trust the certificate that I have obtained via the `openssl` command above?

My related research before resorting to posting:

- [adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list)
- [meteor add trusted certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs)
- [error: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7499)
- [ssl-root-cas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas)

Comment: There is a thing called letsencrypt which can provide you with SSL certs at no charge, and the root CA is now in browsers, which means it works perfectly. No need for the shenanigans with self signed certs any more

Comment: @Mikkel Well that's a way to solve my problem and avoid needing an answer to this question. Nice!

Comment: Maybe I should post it as an answer and you can mark it as correct?