# Jimp Read Url => Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, certificate

I am using Jimp (https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp)

```
Jimp.read(originalUrl)
```

It works like a charm in most case.

If i use it for example with this url => 
`Jimp.read('https://404store.com/2017/12/08/Random-random-30798866-500-325.jpg')`

I get the following error:

> Error
>   unable to verify the first certificate _tls_wrap.js in TLSSocket. at line 1105:38
>   events.js in emitNone at line 106:13
>   events.js in TLSSocket.emit at line 208:7
>   _tls_wrap.js in TLSSocket._finishInit at line 639:8
>   _tls_wrap.js in TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone at line 469:38

---

I want to read the image even if there is a problem with the certificate.
I don't want to configure the behaviour globally to the server.

---

Here is the server configuration :

- Jimp Version: 0.4.0
- Operating System: Ubuntu Server 16.04
- Node version: v8.11.1

I already read this but didn't find the answer I'd like => [Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `rejectUnauthorized: false` in headers.

https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/packages/jimp

> Also, you can pass rejectUnauthorized: false if you don't require an SSL certificate to be valid (it helps to prevent unable to verify the first certificate error).

Do like this:

```
  url: originalUrl, // Required!
  headers: {rejectUnauthorized:false},
  ...
})
```