# HTTPS Gateway API Unable to Verify First Certificate when communicating to HTTPS Microservice

Tags: node.js, express, https, microservices, api-gateway

I'm running an HTTPS gateway API in node/express with a certification acquired from GoDaddy.
The gateway is using the host for the cert and is running on a specific port (not 443, for example 8080).

I can hit the API through various means (cURL, Postman, sample client side), and it responds just fine.

However, because this is a gateway API designed to hit other API microservices on our network, I'm getting the error "unable to verify the first certificate" when I hit a route in the gateway API that is meant to call a microservice.

The microservices are on the same host as the gateway API and are using the same cert for HTTPS, but are listening on different ports.

I can hit the microservices through HTTPS directly with no issue, this error only shows up when I'm hitting the microservice through the gateway API.

When I make the microservices HTTP, the HTTPS gateway gets a successful response from the microservice.

To illustrate:
[image]

Any enlightenment here would be amazing.
I'm still pretty new to SSL certs and I really want to understand what the issue here is.
I've looked at other posts on stackoverflow similar to this issue, but the answers I've come across haven't given me the context I need to fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

I got a working solution for this implemented and I have user sch's explanation from this post to thank:

[Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs)

I followed his instructions to the T and ended up utilizing ssl-root-cas to set the pem chain appropriately.