# cannot access asp.net core api end-poit with next.js front-end 500 internal error reason: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: javascript, next.js, asp.net-core-webapi, fetch-api

I have a ASP.NET Core 5 web API app which works fine and can get and post data with Postman, but when I am trying to access it with my Next.js app I get 500 failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate.
When I try to get fake data from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` it works without any problem.
Do I need especial permission on IIS express?
I'm new to this.
Here is my code for Next.js:

```js
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type","application/json");

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw,
    redirect:'follow'
};

var raw = JSON.stringify({
    "title": "titanic",
    "releaseDate": "1998-10-05",
    "genre": "romance",
    "price": 11.99
})

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://localhost:44310/api/movies`)
    const data = await res.json()

    return {
        props: {movies:data}
    }
}


const Movies = ({movies}) => {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <h1>movies</h1>
            {movies.map(m => (
                <div key={m.id}>
                    <a>
                        <h4>{m.title}</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>    
            ))}
         
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Movies;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs)

Comment: no not really it's not node.js.

Comment: The `fetch` request is being made from `getStaticProps` which runs on the server, in a Node.js environment.

Comment: i have a feeling it's to dp with iis express or my backend which is asp.net core webapi does not allow my front-end to access it