# FetchError: graphql failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, https, graphql

i'm using the graphql-request npm package in order to use graphql in my software.
i have the following line in my code:

```
const client: GraphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(process.env.OCEAN_ENDPOINT, {});
client.setHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer: ${token}` });
```

and then i want to fire a request i use:

```
await client.request(query, variables);
```

until two days ago my endpoint was an http url, but now it changed to https and from that moment i'm getting this error:

```
FetchError: request to https://{graphqlEndpoint}/v1/graphql failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

adding this in env worked for me in nextjs project