# Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, jsdom, magic-mirror

I'm using the jsdom library to scrape data from a website [Weather Related](https://www.senamhi.gob.pe/?p=pronostico-detalle&dp=08&localidad=0019) but this website does not have a complete certificate chain. So I get the following error.

```javascript
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

JSDOM.fromURL('https://www.senamhi.gob.pe/?p=pronostico-detalle&dp=08&localidad=0019').then(dom => {
  console.log(dom.serialize());
});
```

Is there a way I can still connect and get the data from JSDOM?
I've seen some people's suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs) but they are not using JSDOM.
I would appreciate any idea, thanks.