# Get SSL certificate keychain pairs from leaf to root in Nodejs using Hostname or pem file

Tags: node.js, go, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to fetch all the certificates from of ssl using pem or hostname but its returning root certificate only.

I tried following code,

```
const conf = {
                insecureSkipVerify: true
            }

            const conn = tls.connect(443, 'www.facebook.com', conf, () => {
                const certs = conn.getPeerCertificate()
                console.log(`\n PeerCertificate: ${JSON.stringify(certs)}`)
            })

            conn.on('error', (err: any) => {
                console.log('Error in Dial', err)
            })

            conn.on('close', () => {
                conn.destroy()
            })
```

With pem file i tried following code block

```
        // get the SSL certificates from x5u url
        const certificates = (await axios.get(x5u)).data as string

        // getting object of a PEM encoded X509 Certificate.
        const certificate = new X509Certificate(certificates)
        console.log('X509Certificate :-', JSON.stringify(certificate.toLegacyObject()))
```

instead of returning full keychain path its returning root certificate only. I am checking all the leaf to root certificates in ths [SSL-Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)

In golang its returning all the certificates easily but in nodejs its not. I used following code in golang and its working well

```
    conf := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "www.smartsensesolutions.com:443", conf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error in Dial", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    certs := conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates

    for _, cert := range certs {
        fmt.Printf("\nDNSNames: %s \n", cert.DNSNames)
        fmt.Printf("Common Name: %s \n", cert.Issuer.CommonName)
        fmt.Printf("Expiry: %s \n", cert.NotAfter.Format("2006-January-02"))
        fmt.Printf("Valid from: %s \n", cert.NotBefore.Format("2006-January-02"))
        fmt.Printf("SerialNumber: %d \n", cert.SerialNumber)
        fmt.Printf("Signature Algorithm: %s \n", cert.SignatureAlgorithm.String())
        fmt.Printf("Issuer Name: %s\n\n", cert.Issuer)
    }
```

Please help me in nodejs to get all the SSL keychain pairs from host or pem file

I need following output

[image]

Comment: A certificate is not a keychain pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'keychain pair' is not a defined term and has no clear meaning. If you mean *keypair* i.e. the publickey *and* privatekey, you can't get the privatekey or keypair of an SSL/TLS server *or* any of the various CAs used in its trust chain (aka path) (which may be exactly two, less than two, or more than two).

`TLSSocket.getPeerCertificate()` returns the *server* (end-entity or leaf) cert NOT the root. As [clearly stated in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/tls.html#tlssocketgetpeercertificatedetailed), which I guess you didn't read because that would require like doing something vaguely resembling work, if you use `getPeerCertificate(true)` it returns a linked list containing the full chain. See the example I just posted a few days ago (albeit for a different purpose) at [Unable to verify the first certificate in Nodejs while making request and cant install packages using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76688488/unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs-while-making-request-) .

An `x5u` URL is used only for JOSE/JWK, not for SSL/TLS, and an `X509Certificate` object in nodejs contains only one certificate, which will be the FIRST one in the supplied data; for x5u data per rfc7517 the first cert MUST NOT be the root.