# How to call external REST service over SSL from Bluemix

Tags: rest, ssl, ibm-cloud

We have developed a web application using angularjs and html5 and Node.js. This web application is hosted on Bluemix using the Node.js runtime. This web application calls an external RESTfull service (we are invoking the REST service using angularjs) which was developed by a third party. This REST API requires an  HTTPS connection to call the service. The SSL certificate and certificate password are provided by the API development team. Our problem is how to configure the SSL certificate on Bluemix to call the external REST service over SSL from the web application. Can anyone please help us? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you are using the public Bluemix the application is on the public network. You could try the solution provided here that uses Node.js request module to make a call over SSL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254976/how-do-i-use-the-node-js-request-module-to-make-an-ssl-call-with-my-own-certific

Answer (score 0):

To do this properly I would advice to create an API Management Service, where you add your external service as an API together with the SSL settings. You then call this API (proxy) without SSL from your node.js bluemix app.

The proxy will care for SSL, forward the request to the actual service implementation, and provide you also with debugging and analytics capabilities. With having API Management in place, you also benefit from a central place that manages your SSL certificates.