# How to disable ssl check in react native XMLHttpRequest API or in Fetch Api?

Tags: ssl, react-native, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

On local testing server url have ssl certificate error so i have to disable ssl check. I have read many solutions on stackoverflow none of them helped. Problem is i can't make any change on server. So i want to know how to disable ssl check or is there any other api like fetch api or Retrofit for react native.?
My fetch api code as follows

```
fetch('https://example.com/logincheck', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain,',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "username" :"usrname",
  })
})
  .then(response =>  response.json())
  .then(responseobj => {
    this.setState({

    });
    console.log("login status:",responseobj.success);


  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: "url have ssl error so i have to disable ssl check". this is **ABSOLUTELY NOT** the way to go. Fix the TLS problem, do not remove the check. And if you explained a little more about your problem people could have helped you with solutions.

Comment: Actually i have to use local server and no permission to change ssl certificate. In such case i have to ignore ssl check none of the solutions worked. Similar things done using Retrofit in android but not supporting reactnative

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254976/how-do-i-use-the-node-js-request-module-to-make-an-ssl-call-with-my-own-certific

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now to bypass ssl certificate issue.. rn-fetch-blob released. Anyone searching for updated answer please use this answer and check the

> rn-fetch-blob

package.
To connect a server with self-signed certification, you need to add trusty to config explicitly

```
RNFetchBlob.config({
  trusty : true
})
.fetch('GET', 'https://example.com')
.then((resp) => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: that works great thx
free SSL can be overkill for a own server

Comment: can I find something like rn-fetch-blob for expo??

Comment: `rn-fetch-blob` is "Unmaintained" anymore!

Comment: the library does not support an expo app, before using it the app should be ejected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using self signed certificate that's why this problem so instead of self certificate use free ssl refer the following link for further information

[self-signed certificate](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6995)

I'm not suggesting disable the ssl check because this is not a good practice. So please suggest administrator to change self certificate to free ssl. I think you got the answer.