# React-native : self-signed certification implementation

Tags: react-native, ssl, fetch, self-signed-certificate, rn-fetch-blob

Do you known how properly work a **fetch call** with a **self-signed certification** in react-native app ?

#### With a classic fetch :

```
TypeError: Request failed
```

#### With a [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) fetch :

```
[Error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.]
```

#### And a solution to work fine is to ignore the certification, but of course it's not secure.

This code is place on `index.js` file app.

```
const Fetch = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Fetch
window.fetch = new Fetch({
  trusty: true
}).build()
```

I check a different post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130878/how-to-disable-ssl-check-in-react-native-xmlhttprequest-api-or-in-fetch-api/51166411#51166411) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [react-native-ssl-pinning](https://github.com/MaxToyberman/react-native-ssl-pinning), it's work fine with **Certificate pinning**.

And the real problem was coming from a bad install of server certificate.