# How do I retrieve information about client and/or certificate used for a HTTPS request in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, https

Let's say I have this simple code:

```js
const https = require('https')

const agent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true })
const request = https
  .request({ agent, host: 'example.com' }, (response) => {
    response.pipe(process.stdout)
  })
  .end()
```

How do I modify it to retrieve which client and/or server certificate this code uses?
Or do I misunderstand how HTTPS works?

Comment: What do you mean with: "client and/or server certificate this code uses" ?

Comment: @Marc 1. I heard I can do a request using my own certificate to make a request (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254976/how-do-i-use-the-node-js-request-module-to-make-an-ssl-call-with-my-own-certific) - is it just empty when I don't set it explicitly?

Comment: @Marc 2. Retrieve website's certificate from node. I just found the answer so exactly this question doesn't need the answer here anymore